# Reading a text file to a char[][] using try/catch in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, maze

I'm trying to read a maze text file to a double char array, the text file is formatted like so (with the two integers being the number of rows and columns respectively):

```
10 10
##########
#        #
#   ###  #
#   #  G #
#   #    #
#        #
#        #
#  #######
#   S    #
##########
```

My code so far:

```
public char[][] readFile(String filename) {
    char[][] maze = null;
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        int columns = scan.nextInt();

        maze = new char[rows][columns];
        String line;

        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                line = scan.nextLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    maze[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
                }
            }
        } while (scan.hasNextLine());

        scan.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return maze;
}
```

I don't know how to return the array outside the try/catch block. The other posts going over this throw exceptions, which I cannot do due to implementing an interface.

I know initializing the array to null fixes any red flags, but then it spits out a StringIndexOutOfBounds in the console.

Sorry for the ugly code, but I haven't done much coding with file input/output.

Comment: What should the behaviour be if the file is not found?

Comment: can you elaborate on 88I don't know how to return the array outside the try/catch block.**? can you also post the exception that you have got?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the changes within the try/catch block to reflect in your variable outside the try/catch?  Because Java already does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is OK. It simply lacks a call to `scan.nextLine()` **before** entering the first loop, to make the scanner match the end of the first line.

About the exception treatment, it should be like this:

```
public char[][] readFile(String filename)
{
    char[][] maze;
    try
    {
        ...
        maze=<a useful value>
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        maze=<a default value, maybe null>
    }
    return maze;
}
```

The default value should be specified in the interface you are implementing. Or else, to throw a `RuntimeException` from the `catch` block would be the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

you read too many lines...

let's assert your file has 12 lines, 1 line for the size, 10 lines for the maze and a 12th line with some other input.

your code works perfectly for the first 11 lines, but when your code is through with it you should stop reading further!

because it seems after reading the maze once you try to read it again, and i assume you try to read some content that does **not** match your input

```
boolean doneReading = false;
do {
    if(!doneReading){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            line = scan.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                maze[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        //now we have all input, now we can stop reading further
        doneReading = true;
    }
} while (scan.hasNextLine());
```

rather that reading the full file you could simply return the result as soon as you have read it

(alternativ version: return as soon as you can)

```
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        line = scan.nextLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    //now we have all input, now we even return
    return maze;
} while (scan.hasNextLine());
```